# F# in Visual Studio Code type incorrect

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm writing a function to handle postfix evaluation in F#. This is what I currently have for the evaluation function

```
//Postfix evaluation of string expr given variables bound to values as specified in vars
    let (numSt:int list) = []
    let rec innerEval (vars:(List<(string * int)>)) (stack: int list) (expr:string) =
    //Head and Tail for stack, head and tail for expr
        let chExpr = Seq.toList expr
        match expr with 
        |[] -> stack.Head
        |head::tail ->
            if head = '+' then
                let pushVal = stack.Head + stack.Tail.Head
                let newStack = pushVal::stack.Tail
                innerEval vars newStack tail
            elif head = '-' then 
                let pushVal = stack.Head - stack.Tail.Head
                let newStack = pushVal::stack.Tail
                innerEval vars newStack tail
            elif head = '/' then 
                let pushVal = stack.Head / stack.Tail.Head
                let newStack = pushVal::stack.Tail
                innerEval vars newStack tail
            elif head = '*' then 
                let pushVal = stack.Head * stack.Tail.Head
                let newStack = pushVal::stack.Tail
                innerEval vars newStack tail
            elif head = '$' then 
                let fstSt = stack.Head
                let sndSt = stack.Tail.Head
                let nhead = [fstSt; sndSt]
                let st =  nhead @ stack.Tail.Tail
                innerEval vars st tail
            elif head = '@' then 
                let nhead = tail.Head
                let newVars = newVarList nhead vars stack.Head //helper function newVarList
                innerEval newVars stack.Tail tail

             //else it's a letter that needs to give back a number

            else 
                let addNum = (getVal head vars) //get the number
                let newStack = addNum::stack //push that onto stack
                innerEval vars newStack expr //return to recursion on newStack
```

which I know is wordy, but when I try to run this code, I get an error in Code that reads

```
pa4.fs(1194,38): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'string'    
but here has type
    'char'
```

So my question isn't about the code itself necessarily (unless someone can see what's wrong with it) but about the error message: obviously it means I have an element with an incorrect type, but what does the (1194, 38) mean? I'm assuming line 38, but the larger number increases each time I run the code and I'm not sure what it means?

Sorry if this is noob question, was given this task with little to no direction!

Comment: Firstly noob questions are often the best questions, as we want to make things easier for people who are getting started! The 1194 is the line in the console, the 34 is the column. That's why the number gets bigger each time because it also has the previous times you have evaluated things. I personally don't love that default, it works very well for people who are running little bits of their code, but it can be a pain point for people who want to run the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

One of your functions is hoping to get a "string" (many characters I like to think of the party letters being held by a string)  but is instead getting a 'c' 'h' 'a' ,'r' (single character). I'm suspecting newvarlist because innereval looks okay? It's hard to say without looking at the functions, however you should be able to hover over them with your mouse. Both visual studio and visual studio code with the ionide extension support this. You would even get the red squiggles over the lines of code that don't work. Let me know if that was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

F#'s `T list` is an immutable singly-linked list of type `T`, and that's not interchangeable with `string` which is its own primitive type. However, `string` implicitly is `seq<char>`, which is why you can use functions like `Seq.toList expr`.

So it follows that you won't be able to match using the list pattern.

```
let rec innerEval (vars:(List<(string * int)>)) (stack: int list) (expr:string) =
    match expr with //won't compile because expr isn't list
    | [] -> stack.Head
    | head::tail ->
         innerEval vars newStack tail //won't compile because tail is char list
```

An easier solution would be to change the signature of `innerEval (expr: string)` to `innerEval (expr: char list)`, so conversions are simplified.

Comment: @Hailey Dice your question "I know is wordy". More important than fixing a specific error is knowing how to create a minimal examples for diagnosing errors and for asking questions. This answer shows how to do that. What your code does is inessential, so you do not need to preserve functionality. If you keep reducing it while preserving your error you end up with something like this.